# #if Statements in Handlebars

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Ok, I know this is super basic, but I've been staring at it for 2 days and can't see why it is not working.  I am using Handlebars IF helpers to conditionally render a template.

Here is the HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>flash</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{#if isTrue}}
        {{> hello}}
    {{else}}
        {{> goodbye}} 
    {{/if}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
</template>

<template name="goodbye">
    <h1>Goodbye!</h1>
</template>
```

Here is the simple coffee file:

```
isTrue = true
```

I expect the {{> hello}} template to render, but no luck.  I just get the {{> goodbye}} template.  It's odd since I have other projects where I have done this successfully.  I must be missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `isTrue` variable needs to be in a template for it to work. So, put the body contents in a template:

```
<body>
    {{> body}}
</body>

<template name="body">
    {{#if isTrue}}
        {{> hello}}
    {{else}}
        {{> goodbye}} 
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

And then you can define `isTrue` like this:

```
Template.body.helpers
  isTrue: -> true
```

Comment: Hi Sjoerd, I re-implemented and it worked.  Thank you.  What is odd, is that I have another project using if helpers inside the regular HTML body and it works just fine.  Very odd, but this fix got me back on track.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Note:

```
Template.body.isTrue = -> true
```

is now deprecated.

The new syntax looks like this:

```html
Template.test.helpers({
  'isTrue': function(){
    return true;
  }
});
```

It should still work but if you open your console it will give you a warning about the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

with Meteor 1.2.0.2 you can do it like this

```
Template.hello.helpers({
   isTrue() { return true }
});
```